# apache superset clickhouse timestamp format cutting off time

Tags: clickhouse, apache-superset

The Adaptative formatting for superset is cutting the second-minute-hour from the end of my DateTime stamp.

[image: Adaptative formating]

When changed to *%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S* it shows the entire timestamp.

[image: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]

It's stored within clickhouse as "2021-10-20 09:47:30" with the DateTime format and didn't give me any errors.

The main issue is that I cannot customize the time field on other graphs, such as line graphs, meaning it shows everything as if it were done at the same time. Is there any way to fix the Adaptative formatting issue/ set every graph to use *%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S*?

Comment: Do you have the same time zone on Clickhouse and SuperSet server?

How do you check how exactly data stored on clickhouse?
did you use clickhouse-client or some UI like dbeaver / datagrip?